# May the word "envy" be used as a synonym of "desire" or "wish"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, synonyms

I made a (very) litteral translation from french, translating "**envie**" into "**envy**". Though after some research, it seems the word "**envy**" is mostly used to express jealousy. May it be used otherwise as a synonym of "**desire**" or "**wish**" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have found a "false cognate" (*faux ami*) between French and English. The English word "envy" is much more specialized than the French *envie*. From [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/envy):

> ***verb*** [ T ] to wish that you had something that another person has

In other words, the meaning is closer to French *jalousie* than to *envie*. There are a range of alternative translations for *envie* in the general sense, such as "wish," "desire," "want," "long(ing)" or "yearn(ing)." To choose the best option we would need more context regarding what you want to communicate.